# Bring the security message box to the front when using Outlook VBA to send an email

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm writing code to automate sending an email from Excel. Whenever the send function of Outlook is executed, there is a warning/security message box to approve before the email is sent.

The message box is beneath the other forms so the user has to find this message box to proceed with the other tasks.

Is there a way to have this message box appear on top?

Answer (score 2):

The warning message is there for a reason.
However, you can bypass it, but you have to code the functions in C++ and call them from VBA or use a commercial lib that has already done this.
One i've used is: Redemption, [website](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/)

Comment: +1 for "it's there for a reason". When I first read the title "how to bypass a security messagebox", I thought the same thing.

Comment: If you only want: 'Is there a way to have this messagebox appear on top?'.
Maybe via the windows api FindWindow to get the window handle and send a message to put it on top or first.

Comment: I agree on that the box shouldn't be bypassed. Thanks Cody. FindWindow didn't work this time Marcel, but thanks for your suggestion. See below for the solution that I went for.

Comment: That's right its modal, you need to activate its parent window.

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to solve the "messagebox on top" issue by using the following:

```
Set outlookProgram = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 
outlookProgram.ActiveExplorer.Activate
```

Thanks for all you help guys.

P